# How can I sum across multiple sheets using a named range with multiple conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I believe what I am trying to do should be simple in Google Sheets formulae, but any solution based on an Excel formula should be easily transferable.

Because additional characters will be added periodically, I have a named range: "Heroes".

| Heroes |
| --- |
| Bilbo |
| Gandalf |
| Saruman |
| Wormtongue |
| Tom Bombadil |

For each hero, I have a worksheet in one overall workbook.  On these worksheets, there are columns for Date, Time, Quest, and Count.  Several times per day, a hero will venture out on a quest of a certain type, returning with a certain count as a prize.  Each venture has its own row distinguishable by date and time. Eg-:

| Date | Time | Quest | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/4 | 3:00P | Ring | 9 |
| 12/5 | 8:00A | Mordor | 6 |
| 12/5 | 4:15P | Sting | 3 |

Meanwhile, I have a summary worksheet, on which I am manually entering (for now... *bonus points to help create an =arrayformula() or equivalent to grab all unique date/time combinations from each character's worksheet*) the date and time at which one or a batch of heroes are sent to quest.  I am trying to figure out the formula template that will sum the counts for each quest type for each hero at the specific date and time signified by its corresponding row (starting at 12/4, 3:00P, Ring, the count should be 9, for example, which is Bilbo's prize for questing at that time; of course, other heroes are also sent out at 3:00P, resulting in prizes for the other quests, and multiple heroes may venture on the same type of quest at any given time):

| Date | Time | Ring | Sting | Mordor | Moria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/4 | 3:00P | **9** | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 12/4 | 9:30P | 1 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| 12/5 | 8:00A | 5 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 12/5 | 12:10A | 3 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 12/5 | 4:15P | 4 | 5 | 2 | 5 |

Since not every date and time in the summary sheet will exist on each hero's worksheet, I seem unable to use "SUMIFS", which functions in such a way that each sum_range and criteria_range are added on only across the same row when conditions are met.  I think there is a SUMPRODUCT(), or INDEX(MATCH()) way to do this, but when including the named range to read across multiple worksheets, only the first hero's numbers were added in my tinkering with this.

I'm dancing around the solution here.  Anyone care to tango ?  Many thanks !

Sample Workbook for support: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142IE9r2ip6YHsGdMr-zt_IHd6W7glqUId_UiGQnCUZs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be done like this:

```
=QUERY({Bilbo!A:D; Gandalf!A:D; Saruman!A:D; Wormtongue!A:D; 'Tom Bombadil'!A:D}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1)
```

[image]

---

if you want a specific order of places you can do:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 {Bilbo!A:D; Gandalf!A:D; Saruman!A:D; Wormtongue!A:D; 'Tom Bombadil'!A:D}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1)),
 MATCH(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 {Bilbo!A:D; Gandalf!A:D; Saruman!A:D; Wormtongue!A:D; 'Tom Bombadil'!A:D}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1), "limit 0", 1)),
 {"Date"; "Time"; "Ring"; "Sting"; "Mordor"; "Moria"}, ), 1))
```

[image]

or manually like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({Bilbo!A:D; Gandalf!A:D; Saruman!A:D; Wormtongue!A:D; 'Tom Bombadil'!A:D}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6,Col3,Col4")
```

[image]

---

if you thinking to outsmart it with the list of Heroes... don't. referring a range from other sheets requires the usage of `INDIRECT`. and surprise surprise, `INDIRECT` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA` so you cant build an array. at this point, you either re-think your life choices or you use a script where there is support for such indirected arrays. the best you can do without script is to hardcode it like:

```
=QUERY({
 INDIRECT(Main!A2&"!A:D"); 
 INDIRECT(Main!A3&"!A:D"); 
 INDIRECT(Main!A4&"!A:D"); 
 INDIRECT(Main!A5&"!A:D"); 
 INDIRECT(Main!A7&"!A:D")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1)
```

[image]

and ofc this will only work if sheet exists on the list and list does not contain empty cells otherwise you will get **ARRAY** error like this because Main!A6 sheet does not exist:

[image]

so to counter it we can do some slide of hand tricks with `IFERROR` which will allow us to not get the error and still use non-existent sheets and even empty cells so we can pre-program it for future additions like this:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A2="", 0,  Main!A2)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A3="", 0,  Main!A3)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A4="", 0,  Main!A4)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A5="", 0,  Main!A5)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A6="", 0,  Main!A6)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A7="", 0,  Main!A7)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A8="", 0,  Main!A8)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A9="", 0,  Main!A9)&"!A:D"), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A10="", 0, Main!A10)&"!A:D"),{"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(Main!A11="", 0, Main!A11)&"!A:D"),{"","","",""})}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3", 1)
```

[image]

note: 4 columns in range A:D = 4 empty cells {"","","",""}

Comment: This is incredibly detailed; thanks in advance.  One point of clarification regarding your statement: "if you thinking to outsmart it with the list of Heroes... don't."  My list of heroes is a named range, which can be referred to in a formula directly as a single instance, which then returns an array of results; this can be used to refer to multiple sheets with a variable count and names -- just add one more name and the formula don't need addressed at all.  You mention arrayformula, but is that a requirement for using a named range ?

Comment: @AleisterTanekJavasMraz yes, you are right on how named ranges work, but this will work as expected only until you actually want to get data behind references that are located on different sheets/tabs. at such point, you need `INDIRECT` and that will not give you 2 ranges from the namedrange, so `INDIRECT(namedrange)` will output only the 1st range from the named range. so again you will end up with virtual array `{INDIRECT(namedrange); INDIRECT(INDEX(namedrange, 2))}`